# Serving protected static media from django/nginx + streaming from a 3rd party app

Tags: django, nginx

We want to serve protected media from django, using something similar to the django nginx x-accel-redirect setup.

The only problem is that the static files are not located on the public facing django/nginx machine, but in a internal machine that streams the file via http/rest api.

Currently we download the file on the nginx machine and serve it via nginx x-accel-redirect, but we want to optimize this part and looking for options. x-accel-redirect has known problems with files that are streamed from another source.

We are contemplating using django itself as a quasi buffer, but are open to other options as integrating something like whizzer/twisted, or maybe even having another service altogether.

What would be the best option for serving those static files and preserving security?

Comment: This is NOT a Django question anymore since you are explicitly rejecting solutions that use django.

Comment: As I am integrating with a django app, it still would be (using twisted/whizzer would also require something that ties into the ORM). And I am not discarding anything django based, but http-proxy uses the default django method of handling requests, that is not optimized for handling media (and loads all the file in memory which makes it very bad for large files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers

Make your own Django storage backend for the internal machine's http/rest api, that returns 
a File object, and pass that object to filetransfer's server_file function.

That's how I do it in Mayan EDMS https://github.com/rosarior/mayan/blob/master/apps/documents/views.py#L300

django-storages' backends could help you get started.

https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/wiki/Home

Update:

Django_resto appears to have an http based storage class

https://github.com/aaugustin/django-resto/blob/master/django_resto/storage.py#L62

Comment: django-filetransfers default backend for serve file breaks the download files into chunks, which it says itself that is better than using a normal django response, but a lot more inneffient as a nginx redirect would be. ill have to take a good look. thx!

Comment: although not a perfect solution, was the easiest to implement in my somewhat constrained environment and improved results notably.

Answer (score 1):

I had success doing something similar using [django-http-proxy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-http-proxy/0.3).  This assumes that the image server is at least as reliable as the django server.

Then in my urls, I simply mapped the url to the http proxy view, something like:

```
(r'^protected/.*$', 'httpproxy.views.proxy'),
```

Then configured PROXY_FORMAT accordingly.

Comment: as django is inefficient and has memory issues serving media files per se, doesn't really work for us.

Comment: Ummm, ok.  Then remove the line "We are contemplating using django itself as a quasi buffer, but are open to other options as integrating something like whizzer/twisted, or maybe even having another service altogether." from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a simple one-shot signature system in the media machine, using any very thin (django is OK, as it does not need to get to the database) code layer, and x-accel-redirect in nginx.

In the auth machines, generate the correct signature only when the user is allowed to get the resource, and return a 302 to the signed media.

The signature could be time-based, expiring in a fraction of a second, so a sniffer can't use the URL again.

Comment: afaik x-accel-redirect doesnt work well with streaming content as a source for the files (mix between proxying and x-accel-redirect you could say). if you would know how to get that working this could work, but there is currently now way to have nginx running on the machine where the media lives for direct access.

Comment: That's a totally different monster, I assumed you could have not only nginx but also some python/whatever code in that machine to check signatures.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lighttpd to handle the streaming. It has a nice module to protect resources with signatures: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModSecDownload

So I'm thinking you could have nginx just proxy to the streaming server (that's lighttpd).

It's pretty easy to cook up the signature, here's a python example: init.py#cl-27">https://bitbucket.org/ionelmc/django-secdownload-storage/src/be9b18701015/secdownload_storage/**init**.py#cl-27